# How can I make my CodeIgniter instance a property of my PHP class?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've created a User database abstraction class in PHP which extends a base class I made called DBO (database object). The DBO object's job is just to hold `$db` as my codeigniter's `$db` reference.

So ideally, in my User object, I could do `$this->db->insert()` and access my codeigniter's database object.

here's my code:

DBO:

```
class DBO {

    public $db;
    public $ci;

    //put your code here
    public function __construct() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $this->db =& $ci->db;
    }
}
```

USER: (which extends DBO)

```
class User extends DBO{
    /** User id of the user
     * @var int  */
    public $user_id;
    /** User's first name in english
     * @var string  */
    public $first_name;
    /** User's last name in english
     * @var string  */
    public $last_name;
    /** User's name in Korean 
     * @var string */
    public $korean_name;
    /** User's phone number
     * @var string  */
    public $phone;
    /** User's email address
     * @var string  */
    public $email;

    /**
     * Creates a new user from a row or blank.
     * Creates a new user from a database row if given or an empty User object if null
     * 
     * @param Object $row   A row object from table: admin_users
     */
    public function __construct(stdClass $row = null){
        if($row){
            if(isset($row->user_id)) $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
            if(isset($row->first_name)) $this->first_name = $row->first_name;
            if(isset($row->last_name)) $this->last_name = $row->last_name;
            if(isset($row->korean_name)) $this->korean_name = $row->korean_name;
            if(isset($row->phone)) $this->phone = $row->phone;
            if(isset($row->email)) $this->email = $row->email;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Saves this user to the database.
     * @return boolean  Whether this was successfully saved to the database.
     */
    public function create(){
        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'korean_name' => $this->korean_name,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'email' => $this->email,
        );
        if($this->db->insert(Tables::$USERS, $data) && $this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
            $this->user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But whenever I try to use `$this->db->insert()`, it says `Call to a member function insert() on a non-object.`

Is there a way to make this work? Or is it fundamentally wrong? Should my User class ONLY hold the information, and pass a User object to my Users model object and have that run the database functionality?

Thanks for the help

Comment: call parent::__contstruct() in your user class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing call to the parent constructor. Use

```
parent::__contstruct()
```

in your user class constructor. By doing this, the parent class constructor will be called and so the db object will be initialised and you will be able to use it.

You should also read this

http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/inheritance-in-php.html

to understand inheritance. Kindly read about OOPs also so you can get idea of features OOPs in PHP is providing.

Comment: ah, thanks alot! i guess i was used to objects calling their parent constructor at the start of their own constructor automatically.

Comment: If you create a constructor in a chile class, then you have to call the parent constructor in the child constructor, else the on object creation, only the child constructor will be called as you have overloaded the parent constructor. It is the same like function / method overloading. But if there is no constructor in the child class, then the parent class constructor is called.

Comment: thanks again. i've been writing in AS3 for a while, and in that it'll call the parent's constructor automatically if you don't explicitly call it. thanks for catching that error for me!